# ng-repeat limitTo on page scroll to bottom

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, infinite-scroll

I am trying to achieve infinite scroll. On the way I got to know that I can use `limitTo` option on `ng-repeat` to load limited number of records. I have used this on click of a button like this:

**profile.ejs:**

```
<li class="media media-clearfix-xs"  ng-repeat="post in allPosts | limitTo:totalDisplayed" id="october" >

      <!-- Post start here -->
       <!-- Post End here -->

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right" ng-click="loadMore()">Load more</button>
```

**profileController.js:**

```
$scope.totalDisplayed = 5;

$scope.loadMore = function () {
  $scope.totalDisplayed += 5;  
};
```

It is working fine. How can I do the same when user scrolls to bottom of the page. Upon searching for hours I have found some links but no luck. Can anyone please help me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to create one directive that will have scroll event on that element, when the bottom will reach of that element we will call the `scope` function from directive.

**Markup**

```
<ul reached-to-bottom="loadMore()">
    <li ng-repeat="post in allPosts | limitTo:totalDisplayed"></li>
</ul>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('reachedToBottom', function($window, $document){
    return{
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.on('scroll', function(){
                if(element[0].scrollTop + element.innerHeight() == element[0].scrollHeight){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.reachedToBottom);
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried this, `loadMore()` is not getting called on scroll to bottom. What else I am missing?

Comment: @pydev could you create a plunkr whatever I suggested so that I can proceed further help..

Comment: It wil work fine in plunkr, but not working in my app

Comment: @pydev you should follow the same which I suggested in your project

Comment: Yes, I have done the same. Though I am new to plunkr, I have tried to create a plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ngWCD4ppIlGxCncHF8pA?p=preview). Please check this once